# Share Button on a website skips one post before working on the next

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented a drop down share button as shown [Here](https://codepen.io/jacmaes/pen/HJkae) which works but it works after every one post. I am wondering why it works after every one post. What could i be missing?

Javascript:

```
<script>
       $('.social-toggle').on('click', function() {
      $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
      });
       </script>
```

My Html:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="social-toggle">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"> Share This</i></a>

     <div class="social-networks">
      <ul>

        <li class="social-twitter">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url={{STORY}}&amp;text={{TEXT}}&amp;via=Yaye" alt="Tweet this" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>

        <li class="social-facebook">
         <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{STORY}}&title={{TEXT}}" alt="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>

       <li class="social-whatsapp">
        <a href="whatsapp://send?text={{TEXT}}{{STORY}}" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </li>

        <li class="social-telegram">
        <a href="whatsapp://send?text={{TEXT}}{{STORY}}" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i </a>
       </li>

      </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: If I add a few more buttons to your codepen it doesn't seem to replicate the issue (or I'm not understanding the issue). Are you able to create a codepen version with multiple buttons that fails in the way you describe?

Comment: yes i have used the code on codepen with a few editing but now on sharing the first post it works but does nothing on the second then works on the third in that order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled this behavior using `e.preventDefault();` as shown below. Now it works as required.

```
  script>
   $('.social-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
   e.preventDefault();
  });
   </script>
```